# I cannot set number_format excel cell with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Using Openpyxl i can't set correct foramt excel cell

I want to set the following cell format using this code.

```
ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx).number_format = u'# ##0,00 ₽'
```

But in the end, the cell takes a rather strange format: # \ ## 000\ \₽

Please tell me, what could be the problem?

Comment: How is it different if you manually set it?